# Kaltura plugin for Moodle installation problems

Tags: moodle

Anyone who can point me into the right direction? Tried to ask this question over a the Kaltura-forums with no answer. I get this error when I try to register Kaltura CE in Moodle:

"Your Kaltura registration failed.Missing KS. Session not established"

The Kaltura CE installation is working with Drupal, but I cannot make it work with Moodle.

By looking at the code it seems like Moodle is trying to register in order to set up a "Kaltura session" aka KS (via cURL) with the Kaltura CE-server. The installer seems to send the wrong parameters.

- KalturaCE v.3
- Moodle 1.9.9+
- Kaltura Moodle Plugin

Has anyone got the Kaltura-plugin for Moodle to work, if that's the case which versions of KalturaCE and Moodle were you using?

Regards, Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some kind of resolution for that problem posted here: http://www.kaltura.org/config-moodle-mod-moodleadmin-page